# How to convert XML file to pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, xml

I have the following XML and I am trying to convert, some data, into a pandas dataframe:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<DataSet xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
  <xs:schema id="NewDataSet" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
    <xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xs:element name="Radky">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="patente" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="nombre_vehiculo" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="vehículo_id" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="vin" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="fecha" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="wgs_longitud" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="wgs_latitud" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="lugar" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="azimut" type="xs:short" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="altitud_sobre_nivel_de_mar" type="xs:short" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="velocidad" type="xs:short" minOccurs="0" />
              </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
        </xs:choice>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
  </xs:schema>
  <diffgr:diffgram xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1">
    <NewDataSet xmlns="">
      <Radky diffgr:id="Radky1" msdata:rowOrder="0" diffgr:hasChanges="inserted">
        <patente>AASDDDA</patente>
        <nombre_vehiculo>-</nombre_vehiculo>
        <vehículo_id>1234</vehículo_id>
        <vin>5566777</vin>
        <fecha>2021-05-21T14:32:36+02:00</fecha>
        <wgs_longitud>-68.5613264</wgs_longitud>
        <wgs_latitud>-66.3533311</wgs_latitud>
        <lugar>City, Country</lugar>
        <azimut>111</azimut>
        <altitud_sobre_nivel_de_mar>12</altitud_sobre_nivel_de_mar>
        <velocidad>23</velocidad>
      </Radky>
```

I would like to convert values: "patente", "nombre_vehiculo", "vehículo_id", "vin" and so on in a pandas dataframe.

Thanks!

Comment: If you somehow manage to write the dataframe version of this xml, you can get your answer.

Comment: What did you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `read_xml` for loading xml files to a dataframe with pandas : https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_xml.html

Comment: I tried. Nevertheless, I think because is a not a simple xml file I have error trying to parse it.

  self.xml_doc = XML(self._parse_doc(self.path_or_buffer))
  File "src\lxml\etree.pyx", line 3216, in lxml.etree.XML
  File "src\lxml\parser.pxi", line 1896, in lxml.etree._parseMemoryDocument
  File "src\lxml\parser.pxi", line 1784, in lxml.etree._parseDoc
  File "src\lxml\parser.pxi", line 1141, in lxml.etree._BaseParser._parseDoc
  File "src\lxml\parser.pxi", line 615, in lxml.etree._ParserContext._handleParseResultDoc
  File "src\lxml\parser.pxi", line 725, in lxml.etree._handlePa..

Comment: I believe the issue is because I am not declaring namespaces. What it should be ?